# why doesn't this jQuery not find a div with a specific name?

Tags: jquery, html

Why won't this jquery work? 
It's supposed to take the content out of a div named poop and insert it into a div named moreinfo. Instead, there's no content at all in the moreinfo div.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var info = jQuery('poop').text();
jQuery('moreinfo').text(info);
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's all poopy and stuff

Answer (score 4):

'Poop', really?

Well, your code is looking for a `<poop>` tag, not a `<div id="poop">`. To select by ID, use `jQuery('#poop')`.

Answer (score 2):

You might mean:

```
var info = jQuery('#poop').text();
jQuery('#moreinfo').text(info);
```

The `#` means the elements ID, a `.` would mean it's class name

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to select by ID, use:

```
jQuery('#poop')
```

If you're trying to select by class name, use:

```
jQuery('.poop')
```

Basically, use a regular CSS selector...

Answer (score 2):

if the poop and moreinfo are supposed to be class names, then you’ll need to have a dot in before the name.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var info = jQuery('.poop').text();
jQuery('.moreinfo').text(info);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I tried the # before. I tried not including the # because the JQuery for Dummies book didn't use it. 

Anyway, I solved my problem by putting all of my scripts within one script element. Are you not allowed to have multiple script elements in the head?

Comment: You can have as many script tags as possible. When you use it without the . or the #, you’re referencing a specific HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `#` to access IDs, like `jQuery('#moreinfo')`